# What does the Mishnah Berurah in 1:17 mean

Tags: halacha, korban, shacharis-morning-prayer

The Mishnah Berurah in 1:17 cites the Shelah Hakodesh, who says that on shabbos and yomtov we do not recite the teffilah of yehey ratzon since we don't bring a nedaveh on shabbos.  But is this going on the yehey ratzon of the tamid, and if so how can one bring a tamid as a nedaveh?

Answer (score 2):

The Mishna Berura in [1:17](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=10) is referring to the next S'if Katan (1:7) in the Shulchan Aruch.

> כְּשֶׁיְּסַיֵּם פָּרָשַׁת הָעוֹלָה יֹאמַר: יְהִי רָצוֹן מִלְּפָנֶיךָ שֶׁיְּהֵא זֶה חָשׁוּב וּמְקֻבָּל כְּאִלּוּ הִקְרַבְתִּי עוֹלָה, וְכָךְ יֹאמַר אַחַר פ' הַמִּנְחָה וְהַשְּׁלָמִים מִפְּנֵי שֶׁהֵם בָּאִים (יג) בִּנְדָבָה.

This can be corobarated by looking at the  באר היטב  on this S'if; towards the end he quotes the Shela and the rest of the Mishna Berura's quote:

> ועי' בספר זבח השלמים סי' א'. ובתשובת אמונת שמואל סי נ''ג **כתב בשל''ה בשבת וי''ט לא יאמר י''ר דאין קרבן נדבה בא בהם**

(By the way: I don't see a Yehi Razon mentioned for the Tamid, anywhere.)